# Kafka with KRaft - what is listening on the random high port?

Tags: firewall, java, firewalld, openjdk, kafka

I'm in the process of writing some ansible to install Kafka on RHEL and I've got the service running and am about to configure the firewall to make the service accessible on the network.

When I look at what ports are listening on I expect to see `9092` and `9093` - but I see a third port on a random high port number:

```
# ss -lnp | grep java
tcp   LISTEN 0      50                                              *:9092                   *:*    users:(("java",pid=92478,fd=178))                                                             
tcp   LISTEN 0      50                                              *:9093                   *:*    users:(("java",pid=92478,fd=147))                                                             
tcp   LISTEN 0      50                                              *:33641                  *:*    users:(("java",pid=92478,fd=124))
```

If I restart the service the number changes and if I grep through the config there is no reference to the high-port.

What will break if access to the port is blocked by the firewall?

My install follows these instructions:

https://www.conduktor.io/kafka/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-linux-without-zookeeper-kraft-mode/